# Uniform Convergence using Abel's test for a series based on convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

A problem from uniform convergence of series:$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$$ is convergent then show that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty  \frac {nx^n(1-x)}{1+x^n} a_n$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty  \frac {2nx^n(1-x)}{1+x^{2n}} a_n$$ are uniformly convergent when $x \in\ [0,1]$.

Comment: I have tried using Abel's theorem and Dirichlet's theorem. I have not been able to make a headway even after lot of attempts. @Tom-Tom in case you can help, I will be able to save on my study time. Regards

Comment: What do you mean by uniform convergence of  "function $\sum a_n$"? Do you mean that $\sum a_nx^n$ converges uniformly somewhere and then the other two series also converge uniformly exactly where the first one does?

Comment: @uniquesolution : Edited as per comment. No. $\sum a_n$ is given convergent. We have to show the other two series are uniformly convergent. They shall converge to different functions it seems. The question is just to show if the two series are convergent.

Comment: What do you about the radius of convergence ? Try to see what it means for $\sum_na_n=\sum_na_n1^n$.

Comment: @Tom-Tom: I am unable to follow. Can you please elaborate? The link to the problem is here. I am preparing for an exam and am stuck on it since today morning. Requesting your guidance. [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KrPMWIcDVS4C&lpg=PA125&ots=EvTKpi1ErQ&dq=application%20of%20Abel's%20test%20in%20uniform%20convergence&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q=application%20of%20Abel's%20test%20in%20uniform%20convergence&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

As per second thoughts @tom-tom, requesting you to look into this

$ 0\le x \le 1 \Rightarrow x^r \le 1 \quad \forall \ r \ge 0 $

$\Rightarrow 0\le x^{n} \le x^r \quad \forall \ r\le n \ \& \ r \ge 0$

$\therefore \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} x^r \ge n.x^n \ge 0$

$ \Rightarrow \frac {1-x^n}{1-x} \ge nx^n \ge 0$

$\Rightarrow 0\le\frac {nx^n(1-x)}{1-x^n} \le 1$

$$\Rightarrow 0\le\frac {nx^n(1-x)}{1+x^n} \le 1$$

$ \ <b_n(x)>\ = \frac {nx^n(1-x)}{1+x^n}$ is bounded.

$\sum a_n$  is given as convergent. As it is free from $x$, $\therefore$ it is uniformly convergent.

Now, $ \ 1. \ <a_n(x)> $ is uniformly convergent,
     $ \ 2. \ <b_n(x)> $ is bounded for $ x \in [0,1] \ $, $\quad$ 3. $\ <b_n(x)> $ shall be piecewise monotonic.

$\therefore$ $ \quad \sum a_n(x) b_n(x)$ shall be uniformly convergent.

$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^\infty  \frac {nx^n(1-x)}{1+x^n} a_n \ $$ is convergent.

Similarly other one can be proved. Please let me know of mistakes, if any.